# End User Authentication using Neo4j

Tags: sql-server, security, authentication, neo4j, graph-databases

Currently I have a website which uses MS SQL 2008 and the Microsoft Membership Provider to create/authenticate users, this works fine.
We have migrated all of our 'data' over to Neo4j, which has gone really well and everything works, but we are not sure at this point the best way of managing the authentication system.

So the question is, what is the standard way to store/retrieve credentials and other sensitive information and perform authentication using a graph database.
Is it ideal to store the credentials data in the graph, or should we still use MSSQL and the Membership provider we already have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [authentication feature introduced in Neo4j 2.2](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/security-server.html#security-server-auth) is just a "all or nothing" based on username / password.

If you need a more fine grained approach you need to implement your own [security rules](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/security-server.html#_server_authorization_rules).

Comment: I am struggling to find an API to create new users though, any ideas?

Comment: there was a blog post from Robin Bramley: https://leanjavaengineering.wordpress.com/2015/04/16/neo4j-2-2-authentication-and-adding-extra-users/

Comment: To be honest I am a little confused as to the best way to manage this, it's a little bit me not thinking correctly.
Where would you store user data?

Comment: Should anyone ever wonder, I ended up keeping my membership system and using this to store the auth data in Neo4j: https://github.com/coreyauger/Neo4JMembershipProvider, we are working on some improvements.